# How to resolve keybinding-conflicts in atom.io

Tags: plugins, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, asciidoc

I installed the atom.io plugins `git-plus` and `asciidoc-preview`.

Unfortunately both claim the keybinding `Ctrl + Shift + A`. There is no warning shown in the keybinding-settings.

[image: atom.io settings for key-bindings]

How to solve this Problem? Should I manually add the `*.cson` files and add another keybinding? Or is there a way to do it directly in atim.io?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can override the key binding and manually set it to the command you want to run:

1. Open the Key Binding Resolver (`Ctrl + Shift + P`, type `Resolver`).
2. Press your key binding in question (`Ctrl + Shift + A`).
3. The Resolver will show all the commands and the selectors associated with that key binding. The one that took precedence is highlighted, and the ones that are ignored are not highlighted. Make a note of the highlighted command in the first column or the selector in the second column (looks like a CSS selector).

[image]

4. Go to the Settings > Key bindings screen.
5. Search for the command or selector and click the clipboard button in the leftmost column of its row. This puts it into your clipboard.
6. Open your keymap.cson (`Ctrl + Shift + P`, type `Open keymap`).
7. Paste the selector.
8. Override the command associated with that selector. Using the most specific selector from your screenshot as an example, this will make the `Ctrl + Shift + A` key binding run the `git-plus:add` command:

`'.platform-win32 atom-workspace, .platform-win32 atom-workspace atom-text-editor, .platform-linux atom-workspace, .platform-linux atom-workspace atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-shift-A': 'git-plus:add'`

<strike>Alternatively, you can use a package such as *disable-keybindings* or *keymap-disabler* to disable key bindings on a per package basis: https://discuss.atom.io/t/disable-default-keybindings/1077/36</strike>.

**Updates:**

**As of Atom version 1.1**: [The feature for disabling keybindings per package is now core.](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/8130)

**As of Atom version 1.12**: [User key bindings now take precedence over package key bindings regardless of their selector specificity](http://blog.atom.io/2016/11/09/atom-1-12.html).

Comment: This needs getting used to. Now I understood, that each definition of a key-binding consists of the scope (e.g. "editor window") the keystroke and the command. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Atom version used: 1.15.0**

- go to settings: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>
- go to *Keybindings* tab
- type your command, it'll show all the keybindings associated with your comand
- save the keybinding by clicking on the copy button. It'll save it to your clipboard.
  a
  [image: copy cutton]
- type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and enter keymap. Click on *Application: Open your keymap*
- go to bottom of the file. Paste the keybinding <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

Done! You should now be able to use your command which atom sorts with higher preference.